# Creating a derived table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need some help summing two (or more) alias columns.
I know I need a derived table to do it, but so far I get lost with online tutorials and documentation as their examples are far too simple. they only have one table, two columns, etc.

What could be my best option here:
I need to calculate the sum of two alias columns: 'InFxO' and 'OnTxO' and my code is as follows:

```
 ALTER PROC [dbo].[DIFOTIS]
@Mode as Varchar (5)
AS
Begin
Declare

@StartDate date,
@EndDate date

SET @StartDate=
CASE @Mode
WHEN 'MTD' THEN DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)
WHEN 'YTD' THEN DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0)
WHEN 'QTD' THEN DATEADD(qq,DATEDIFF(qq,0,GETDATE()),0)
WHEN 'WTD' THEN DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()),0)
END
Set @EndDate=
CASE @Mode
WHEN 'MTD' THEN DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())+1,0)
WHEN 'YTD' THEN DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE())+1,0)
WHEN 'QTD' THEN DATEADD(qq,DATEDIFF(qq,0,GETDATE())+1,0)
WHEN 'WTD' THEN DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE())+1,0)
END


Select DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,d.DateOpn) AS 'Week#'
 ,Clients.CustCateg, Clients.ClntGroup
 ,d.DocumentCode as 'CORD_DocumentCode'
 ,CDSPDocs.DocumentCode AS 'DESP_DocumentCode'
 ,Count(CORDLines.Qnty) AS 'Cord_Lines'
 ,SUM(CORDLines.Qnty) AS 'CORD_Qty'
 ,Count(CDSPLines.Qnty) AS 'DESP_Lines'
 ,Sum(CDSPLines.Qnty) AS 'DESP_Qty'
 ,CDSPLines.Status, d.Status as d_status
 ,d.OpenDate, d.DateDue
 ,CDSPDocs.PostDate AS 'DESP_PostedDate'
 ,d.DocType, DATEDIFF(day, d.OpenDate, d.DateDue) AS 'Lead times'

    --in-full

 ,CASE WHEN SUM(CORDLines.Qnty) = Sum(CDSPLines.Qnty) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as InFxO


    --On-Time by order according to Despatch SLAs 

 ,CASE WHEN (Clients.ClntGroup IN ('Local Market','Local Market - Pharm','Web Sales - Local','Web Sales - Export', 'Mail Order','Mail Order - Export')) AND (Datediff(day, d.OpenDate, CDSPDocs.PostDate) - (Datediff(Week, d.OpenDate, CDSPDocs.PostDate)*2) <= 2) then '1' 
       WHEN (Clients.ClntGroup = 'Export Market') AND (Datediff(day, d.OpenDate, CDSPDocs.PostDate) - (Datediff(Week, d.OpenDate, CDSPDocs.PostDate)*2) <= 14) then '1'
       WHEN (Clients.ClntGroup = 'Export Market') or Clients.CustCateg = 'UK Transfer' AND (d.DateDue >= CDSPDocs.PostDate) then '1'
       ELSE '0'
       END  as OnTxO 


From dbo.Documents AS d INNER JOIN
    dbo.Clients ON d.ObjectID = dbo.Clients.ClntID  AND Clients.ClientName <> 'Samples - Free / Give-aways' LEFT Outer JOIN
    dbo.DocumentsLines AS CORDLines ON d.DocID = CORDLines.DocID AND CORDLines.TrnType = 'L' 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.DocumentsLines AS CDSPLines ON CORDLines.TranID = CDSPLines.SourceID AND CDSPLines.TrnType = 'L' AND (CDSPLines.Status = 'Posted' OR CDSPLines.Status = 'Closed') LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Documents AS CDSPDocs ON CDSPLines.DocID = CDSPDocs.DocID 

WHERE  (d.DocType IN ('CASW', 'CORD','MORD'))  
 AND (CORDLines.LneType NOT In ('Fght','MANF','Stor', 'PACK','EXPS')) 
 AND d.DateOpn  >= @StartDate AND d.DateOpn < @EndDate 
 AND (CORDLines.LneType is not null) 
 AND (d.DateDue <= Convert(Date, GetDate(), 101)) 

Group by d.DateOpn
 ,d.DocumentCode
 ,Clients.CustCateg
 ,CDSPDocs.DocumentCode
 ,d.[Status]
 ,d.DocType
 ,d.OpenDate
 ,d.DateReq
 ,CDSPDocs.PostDate
 ,CDSPLines.[Status]
 ,Clients.ClntGroup
 ,d.DocumentName
 ,d.DateDue
 ,d.DateOpn

ORDER BY d.DateOpn, 'Week#'
    END


GO
```

All help is appreciated.
Thanks
H

Comment: You mention SUM the InFxO and OnTxO columns, but those expressions currently return a varchar rather than a numeric value.  Is your intent for the CASE espressions to return a integer value 0 or 1?  Do you simply want encapsulate the entire query in a derived table, and return a single row with the SUM of those 2 expressions?

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for your reply. My intention is to return an Integer in both alias column and have them SUM in a third column (InFxO + OnTxO)...then use the result in a calculated field within SSRS 'iif "2" then...
Apologies but I do not know what you mean with encapsulate the entire query...I am fairly new to this SQL world and some of the "best practices" are beyond my scope. I  am open to ideas if these will improve my query and teach me how to do it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example that wraps the original query in a derived table so that you don't need to repeat the CASE expressions for the SUM.  You could similarly wrap the query in a common table expression to achieve the same result.

I suggest you use single-quotes only to enclose string literals and enclose identifiers (column names, aliases, and object names) with either square brackets or double quotes as described in the SQL Server Books Online reference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx).  Identifiers need be enclosed only when they don't conform to identifier naming rules or are a reserved keyword.

```
ALTER PROC dbo.DIFOTIS @Mode AS varchar(5)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @StartDate date
          , @EndDate date;

        SET @StartDate = CASE @Mode
                           WHEN 'MTD'
                           THEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
                           WHEN 'YTD'
                           THEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
                           WHEN 'QTD'
                           THEN DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
                           WHEN 'WTD'
                           THEN DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
                         END;
        SET @EndDate = CASE @Mode
                         WHEN 'MTD'
                         THEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
                         WHEN 'YTD'
                         THEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
                         WHEN 'QTD'
                         THEN DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
                         WHEN 'WTD'
                         THEN DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
                       END;

      SELECT  Week#
              , CustCateg
              , ClntGroup
              , CORD_DocumentCode
              , DESP_DocumentCode
              , Cord_Lines
              , CORD_Qty
              , DESP_Lines
              , DESP_Qty
              , Status
              , d_status
              , OpenDate
              , DateDue
              , DESP_PostedDate
              , DocType
              , [Lead times]
              , InFxO
              , OnTxO
              , InFxO + OnTxO AS InFullAndOneTime
        FROM (

            SELECT  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, d.DateOpn) AS Week#
                  , Clients.CustCateg
                  , Clients.ClntGroup
                  , d.DocumentCode AS CORD_DocumentCode
                  , CDSPDocs.DocumentCode AS DESP_DocumentCode
                  , COUNT(CORDLines.Qnty) AS Cord_Lines
                  , SUM(CORDLines.Qnty) AS CORD_Qty
                  , COUNT(CDSPLines.Qnty) AS DESP_Lines
                  , SUM(CDSPLines.Qnty) AS DESP_Qty
                  , CDSPLines.Status
                  , d.Status AS d_status
                  , d.OpenDate
                  , d.DateDue
                  , CDSPDocs.PostDate AS DESP_PostedDate
                  , d.DocType
                  , DATEDIFF(DAY, d.OpenDate, d.DateDue) AS [Lead times]

        --in-full
                  , CASE WHEN SUM(CORDLines.Qnty) = SUM(CDSPLines.Qnty) THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
                    END AS InFxO
        --On-Time by order according to Despatch SLAs 
                  , CASE WHEN ( Clients.ClntGroup IN ( 'Local Market',
                                                       'Local Market - Pharm',
                                                       'Web Sales - Local',
                                                       'Web Sales - Export',
                                                       'Mail Order',
                                                       'Mail Order - Export' ) )
                              AND ( DATEDIFF(DAY, d.OpenDate, CDSPDocs.PostDate)
                                    - ( DATEDIFF(WEEK, d.OpenDate,
                                                 CDSPDocs.PostDate) * 2 ) <= 2 )
                         THEN 1
                         WHEN ( Clients.ClntGroup = 'Export Market' )
                              AND ( DATEDIFF(DAY, d.OpenDate, CDSPDocs.PostDate)
                                    - ( DATEDIFF(WEEK, d.OpenDate,
                                                 CDSPDocs.PostDate) * 2 ) <= 14 )
                         THEN 1
                         WHEN ( Clients.ClntGroup = 'Export Market' )
                              OR Clients.CustCateg = 'UK Transfer'
                              AND ( d.DateDue >= CDSPDocs.PostDate ) THEN '1'
                         ELSE 0
                    END AS OnTxO
            FROM    dbo.Documents AS d
                    INNER JOIN dbo.Clients ON d.ObjectID = dbo.Clients.ClntID
                                              AND Clients.ClientName <> 'Samples - Free / Give-aways'
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DocumentsLines AS CORDLines ON d.DocID = CORDLines.DocID
                                                                  AND CORDLines.TrnType = 'L'
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DocumentsLines AS CDSPLines ON CORDLines.TranID = CDSPLines.SourceID
                                                                  AND CDSPLines.TrnType = 'L'
                                                                  AND ( CDSPLines.Status = 'Posted'
                                                                  OR CDSPLines.Status = 'Closed'
                                                                  )
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Documents AS CDSPDocs ON CDSPLines.DocID = CDSPDocs.DocID
            WHERE   ( d.DocType IN ( 'CASW', 'CORD', 'MORD' ) )
                    AND ( CORDLines.LneType NOT IN ( 'Fght', 'MANF', 'Stor',
                                                     'PACK', 'EXPS' ) )
                    AND d.DateOpn >= @StartDate
                    AND d.DateOpn < @EndDate
                    AND ( CORDLines.LneType IS NOT NULL )
                    AND ( d.DateDue <= CONVERT(date, GETDATE(), 101) )
            GROUP BY d.DateOpn
                  , d.DocumentCode
                  , Clients.CustCateg
                  , CDSPDocs.DocumentCode
                  , d.Status
                  , d.DocType
                  , d.OpenDate
                  , d.DateReq
                  , CDSPDocs.PostDate
                  , CDSPLines.Status
                  , Clients.ClntGroup
                  , d.DocumentName
                  , d.DateDue
                  , d.DateOpn
        ) AS derived_table
        ORDER BY d.DateOpn
              , Week#;
    END;
GO
```